# LinkButton On_Command event not working due to ModalPopupExtender & ASP:Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am creating data manage form and I am attaching ajaxcontroltoolkit  for modal popup panel. after adding modelpopupextender and asp:panel in the web from LinkButton's OnCommend & OnClick not working. 
here is a complete code of my web form:-

```
> <%@ Page Title="Manage Job Title" Language="C#"
> MasterPageFile="~/Portal.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
> CodeBehind="LInkedin-Manage-JobTitle.aspx.cs"
> Inherits="Forms.LInkedin_Manage_JobTitle" %>
> 
> <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
> Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %> <asp:Content
> ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
> </asp:Content> <asp:Content ID="Content2"
> ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
>     <style>
>         .modalBackground {
>             height: 100%;
>             background-color: #EBEBEB;
>             filter: alpha(opacity=70);
>             opacity: 0.7;
>         }
>     </style>
> 
>     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
>     <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
> 
>     <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="Button1"
> CancelControlID="Button4"
> BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
>     <asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" Style="display: none">
>         <div class="col-lg-12">
>             <div class="panel panel-primary">
>                 <div class="panel-heading">
>                     Add Job Title
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="panel-body">
>                     <div class="row">
>                         <div class="col-lg-12">
>                             <asp:TextBox MaxLength="20" ID="txtjobtitle" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"
> placeholder="Enter Job Title"></asp:TextBox>
>                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtjobtitle" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
> runat="server" Text="* Job Title Must be Required"
> ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="row">
>                         <div class="col-lg-6">
>                             <asp:Button ID="AddJobtitle" runat="server" Text="Insert" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
> OnClick="AddJobtitle_Click" />
>                         </div>
>                         <div class="col-lg-6">
>                             <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </asp:Panel>
> 
>     <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
>         <div class="col-lg-12">
>             <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col-lg-10">
>                     <span style="font-size: 20px">Managed Job Titles</span>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="col-lg-2">
>                     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Job Title" CssClass="btn btn-primary  " Style="margin-bottom: 10px;"
> />
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>             <hr />
>             <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col-lg-12">
>                     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
> AutoGenerateColumns="false">
>                         <Columns>
>                             <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
>                             <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Job Title" />
>                             <asp:BoundField DataField="addedDt" HeaderText="Added Date" />
>                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="50" ItemStyle-Width="50">
>                                 <ItemTemplate>
>                                     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="fa fa-remove" ToolTip="Delete Job Title"
> CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'
> OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
>                                     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="fa fa-edit" ToolTip="Edit Details"
> CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'
> OnCommand="LinkButton2_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
>                                 </ItemTemplate>
>                             </asp:TemplateField>
>                         </Columns>
>                     </asp:GridView>
>                     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
> 
>         </div>
>     </div> </asp:Content>
```

and here is view code of this page:-

```
public partial class LInkedin_Manage_JobTitle : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DevSocialListening"].ConnectionString);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Bind();
            }
        }
        private void Bind()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from jobTitle", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }


        protected void AddJobtitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataAcsess d = new DataAcsess();
            d.AddNewJobTitle(txtjobtitle.Text);
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Saved')</script>");
            Bind();

            txtjobtitle.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void LinkButton2_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        }
```

please give me a suggestion for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have RequiredField validator inside Panel  control and button click and link command is not firing due to failing validation.

To fix this issue, add “ValidationGroup” attribute on your required field validatior and also add same validation group attribute on the Save button inside panel. This will limit the required field validation to only Save button click inside Panel.